# lambda expression cast from interface

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, casting

I have following interface:

```
public interface IHasSchoolId
{
    long? SchoolId { get; set; }
}
```

and following entity:

```
public class Student : IHasSchoolId
{
    long? SchoolId { get; set; }
}
```

then there is following entity manager implementing empty interface `IEntityManager<T>`:

```
public class HasSchoolIdManager: IEntityManager<IHasSchoolId>
{
    public static Expression<Func<IHasSchoolId, bool>> Filter()
    {
        return x=> x.SchoolId != null; //this is just an example
    }
}
```

and finally I have following method:

```
private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetFilters<TEntity>()
{
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> result = null;
    var entityManagers = //geting entitymanagers that are assinable to TEntity, like the one above and a lot more like IEntityManager<Student> itself
    foreach (var entityManager in entityManagers)
    {
        var filterMethod = entityManager.GetMethod("Filter");
        if (filterMethod != null)
            result = AndAlso(result, (Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>) filterMethod.Invoke(null, null)); //this line throws exception
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then when I'm calling the method like `GetFilters<Student>()` im getting following exception:

> **System.InvalidCastException**: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[WebCore.Models.Infrastructure.Interfaces.IHasSchoolId,System.Boolean]]' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[System.Func[WebCore.Models.Student,System.Boolean]]'.'

by the way, this is my AndAlso method which works fine:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> AndAlso<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
{
    if (expr1 == null)
        return expr2;
    if (expr2 == null)
        return expr1;
    ParameterExpression param = expr1.Parameters[0];
    if (ReferenceEquals(param, expr2.Parameters[0]))
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, expr2.Body), param);
    }
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.AndAlso(
            expr1.Body,
            Expression.Invoke(expr2, param)), param);
}
```

and here is my empty IEntityManager interface:

```
public interface IEntityManager<T>
{

}
```

**Note**: not all my entities implements IHasSchoolId interface, there are many other interfaces, this is just an example

i think my question is, how to cast from `Expression<Func</*an interface*/, bool>>` to `Expression<Func</*a class that implements that interface*/, bool>>`
using reflection because as you can see, im calling the filter method using reflection

Comment: Kindly show the `IEntityManager` interface

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, and you didn't show the code for the manager interface (I know it's empty, but still required), so I assume you defined it with the interface. Instead, try making the manager interface generic and restrict it to the interface, like this `public interface IEntityManager<TEntity> where TEntity : IHasSchoolId`.

Comment: Please post the line of code that throws the exception.

Comment: @JohnWu He already did. See the comments in code for the method (you need to scroll to the right to see it).

Comment: @user4111079 did you find the solution? I am also searching the exact same
my code is sth like this

```public class FilterQueryable
    {

        public Expression<Func<IHasCreator, bool>> forCurrentUser;


        public FilterQueryable(UserValues userValues)
        {

            forCurrentUser = p => p.CreatorId == userValues.Identifier;

        }

    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what i finally did:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null;
var managers = GetEntityManagers<T>();
foreach (var manager in managers)
{
    var expr2 = manager.GetMethod("Filter")?.Invoke(null, null) as dynamic;
    if (expr2 == null) continue;
    var transformedExpr = Transform<T>(expr2) as Expression<Func<T, bool>>;
    expression = expression == null ? transformedExpr : expression.AndAlso(transformedExpr);
}
```

and here is the transform function:

```
private class Visitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private Expression _parameter;

    public Visitor(Expression parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameter;
    }
}

private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Transform<T>(dynamic expression)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = new Visitor(parameter).Visit(expression.Body);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
}
```